# Multiple Select All buttons causing problems with interactivity in Shiny map

Tags: r, dictionary, shiny, leaflet

I'm coding an interactive map in R with Shiny and Leaflet. I programmed 1 select all button for the months (checkGroup) and it worked fine, but adding the select all button for the other inputs has caused none of the map to work properly.

```
#import data
data <- structure(list(Area = c("Scarborough", "Etobicoke", "East York", 
"North York", "North York", "Etobicoke", "Downtown Core (Central)", 
"York", "Downtown Core (Central)", "York"), occurrenceyear = c(2017L, 
2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L
), occurrencemonth = structure(c(12L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
12L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("", "April", "August", "December", 
"February", "January", "July", "June", "March", "May", "November", 
"October", "September"), class = "factor"), Long = c(-79.1886063, 
-79.5458221, -79.3138199, -79.4392548, -79.4406738, -79.5390091, 
-79.3820572, -79.4840012, -79.3930817, -79.4356079), Lat = c(43.7639694, 
43.5895691, 43.6753197, 43.7586555, 43.727829, 43.6431503, 43.6683502, 
43.6842308, 43.6707535, 43.6820869)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Interactive Toronto Auto Theft Visualization"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup", h3("Month"), choices = list("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August" ,"September", "October", "November", "December"), selected = "Janurary"),
      actionLink("selectall", "Select All"),
      checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup2", h3("Year"), 
                  choices = list(2014, 2015,2016 , 2017, 2018 ), selected = 2018),
      actionLink("Selectall2", "Select All"),
      checkboxGroupInput("checkGroup3", "Toronto Neighbourhoods", choices = list("Downtown Core (Central)", "East End", "North End", "West End", "East York", "Etobicoke", "North York", "Scarborough", "York"), selected = "York"),
      actionLink("Selectall3", "Select All")

    ), 
    mainPanel (leafletOutput("map", "100%", 500))
  ))


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    if(input$selectall == 0) return(NULL)
       else if(input$selectall%%2==0)
         {
         updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", "Month", choices = list("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August" ,"September", "October", "November", "December"))
       }
       else
       {
         updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup", "Month", choices = list("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August" ,"September", "October", "November", "December"), selected = list("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August" ,"September", "October", "November", "December"))
       }

    if(input$Selectall2 == 0) return(NULL)
      else if(input$Selectall2 %%2 == 0)
      {
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup2", "Year", choices = list(2014, 2015,2016 , 2017, 2018))
      }
        else
        {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "checkGroup2", "Year", choices = list(2014, 2015,2016 , 2017, 2018), selected = list(2014, 2015,2016 , 2017, 2018))
        }
  })

    filtered <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$checkGroup) & is.null(input$checkGroup2) & is.null(input$checkGroup3)){
        return (NULL)
      }
      data %>% filter(occurrencemonth %in% input$checkGroup & occurrenceyear %in% input$checkGroup2 & Area %in% input$checkGroup3)
    })


  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet()%>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB") %>%
      addCircleMarkers(data = filtered(), radius = 2)
  })
}
```

I believe the problem is in the observe function because that is where the programming for the select all buttons are placed. I've only programmed 2 of the buttons before running into the problem and was trying to fix the issue before adding in the third button (selectall3).

I've tried creating two separate observe functions for the two separate buttons, but that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have typo here:

```
if(input$selectall2 == 0) return(NULL)
```

Should be:

```
if(input$Selectall2 == 0) return(NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've noticed though that deselecting the month values also deselects the year values. Selecting the year values also deselects the month values.  I don't want any of these to be interrelated. Is there anything I can do about that?

Comment: Creating separate observe functions seemed to have fixed it!